# getStringExtra returns null SINGLE_TOP flag

Tags: android

I made one Fragment (ListA) with a ListView. When I click one item of the ListView I want to start the MainActivity.

```
public class ListA extends Fragment {

    private WearableListView ListV;

    ...

    private WearableListView.ClickListener mClickListener = new WearableListView.ClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(WearableListView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("timestamp", "AAA");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(getIntent().getStringExtra("timestamp")!=null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Has Timestamp",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I add flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, getIntent().getStringExtra("timestamp") returns null. If I add flag            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK it is not null.
 I want to have flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and it returns null, I  don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think because MainActivity was already started before so no new intents is being passed to it.

Try destroying the main activity before you go to list activity. See if this works